# ReactNode can't be JSX Element

Tags: reactjs

I have a component that display different `ReactNode` based on the props passed.
It basically looks like this

```
interface RestrictedFieldProps{
  restrictedTo: LogisticFeatureFlag[];
  fallback?: React.ReactNode;
  loadingComponent?: React.ReactNode;
}

export const RestrictedField = ({
  restrictedTo,
  fallback = null,
  loadingComponent = null,
  children,
}: React.PropsWithChildren<RestrictedFieldProps>) => {
  const { loading, isAllowed } = usePermissionCtx({ restrictedTo });

  if (loading) {
    return loadingComponent
  }

  if (!isAllowed) {
    return children
  }

  return fallback;
};
```

Now, I have an issue with this, when I use the component I get prompted.

> 'RestrictedBrandField' cannot be used as a JSX component.
> Its return type 'ReactNode' is not a valid JSX element.
> Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'Element | null'.ts(2786)

Fine, I don't see where I do return an undefined but I tried to change to.

```
  if (loading) {
    return <>{loadingComponent}</>;
  }

  if (!isAllowed) {
    return <>{children}</>;
  }

  return <>{fallback}</>;
```

But I get a warning from eslint

> Fragments should contain more than one child - otherwise, there’s no need for a Fragment at all.

Not good also...

What should I do in such case ? Is eslint wrong ?

Comment: what are you passing to loadingComponent and fallback?

Comment: a component or HTML like could be just `<div>Loading</div>`

Comment: What happens if you use the type `JSX.Element` instead of `ReactNode`? I believe `ReactNode` has `undefined`, as well as some other extra types, baked into it, so that's probably where your ESLint warning is coming from

Comment: For second error, you don't need to wrap the element with fragment. Change it to `if (loading && loadingComponent) {
    return {loadingComponent};
  }`

Comment: JSX.Element don7t throw error within the component, but when I use it it say 
> 'RestrictedFieldProps' cannot be used as a JSX component.
  Its return type 'string | number | boolean | ReactFragment | Element | null | undefined' is not a valid JSX element.
    Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'Element | null'. 

Event tho I never render undefined since I put default value as null

Answer (score 0):

Wrapping the variable in a Fragment is correct. There is an ESList configuration specifically to allow this case:

```
'react/jsx-no-useless-fragment': [2, { allowExpressions: true }]
```

[Rule documentation is here](https://github.com/jsx-eslint/eslint-plugin-react/blob/master/docs/rules/jsx-no-useless-fragment.md#allowexpressions)